# ¿Como poner base de datos local -portable- en c# (visual studio 2015, sql server compact)?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, visual-studio-2015

Estaba haciendo un sistema en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), lo tenia conectado con una base de datos en *access*. Pero me di cuenta que tal vez no podía; Generar el instalador del programa y pasárselo a otra persona.
Alguien me dijo que intentara ponerle una base de datos de *Sql Server Compact*, así, ya no tendría que preocuparme de poner una cadena de conexión como `"C:/Users/NombreUsuario/BaseDeDatos.accdb"`
Lo que tenia que hacer, era agregar mi base de datos de Sql Server Ce al proyecto y poner la cadena de conexión en el `App.config` del proyecto.
Agregue una base de datos dando clic al nombre del proyecto> agregar> "Base de datos basada en servicio". Si quiera me dejo cambiar el nombre, Visual Studio la genero con el nombre `DataBase1.mdf` junto con otro archivo llamado `DataBase1DataSet.xsd`. Pero realmente no se como hacerlo.
Intente buscar algunos tutoriales en youtube o en foros. Pero en muchos utilizan una referencia a `System.Data.SqlServerCe` que no tengo y no puedo descargar desde NuGet.

¿Como lo puedo hacer? (Incluir base de datos local y poder ponerla en el proyecto para, generar el instalador del programa y correrlo en cualquier computadora sin necesidad de servidor)
Saludos y espero no haberte confundido.

Comment: Hace días tuve ese problema, mi solución fue pasar la base de datos a SQLite te recomiendo esta pagina: [SQLite in C# Net 4.0](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Answer (score 4):

**>>asi, ya no tendria que preocuparme de poner una cadena de conexion como "C:/Users/NombreUsuario/BaseDeDatos.accdb"**

Pero con Ms Access no necesitas poner una ruta completa sino lo requieres.

Si el archivo accdb esta junto al .exe puedes usas el |DataDirectory| para hacer referencia a la db

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDatos.accdb;
```

Persist Security Info=False;

**>>Visual Studio la genero con el nombre DataBase1.mdf junto con otro archivo llamado DataBase1DataSet.xsd.**

La extension `.mdf` es un archivo de Sql Server, esto no seria Sql Compact ya que la extension deberia ser `.sdf`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: no encontre una imagen de VS2015, pero el item deberia ser similar al de la imagen o al menos la extension deberia ser sdf

Quizas ayude esta tool

[SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)

por medio de esta podrias crear y administrar la db

[Visual Studio 2015 Community SQL Server Compact 4.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6TAR4LWdAw)